# Does apps backup on iCloud consume space?

Tags: iphone, icloud

iCloud comes with free 5GB space. If I enable iCloud to backup my iPhone app (10GB+), is the app size counted as part of the 5GB space? Or only the data of apps is counted?

Comment: For $150/- can get a 3 year fully paid plan your own server space, with ftp, secure ftp, ssl, php, mail etc. There should be apps where you can specify custom server and back up everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything on your iPhone that Apple sells in its stores (that is, any music, apps, movies, books, etc. you've purchased and *are still available*) will be backed up and won't count towards the 5GB total.

That doesn't include, obviously, app data, your photos and videos, SMS and the like (from [iCloud: Backup and restore overview](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4859)):

> **What is backed up**
>
> You get unlimited free storage for:
>
> - Purchased music, movies, TV shows, apps, and books
>
>   (...)
>
> You get 5 GB of free iCloud storage for:
>
> - Photos and videos in the Camera Roll
> - Device settings (for example: Phone Favorites, Wallpaper, and Mail, Contacts, Calendar accounts)
> - App data
> - Home screen and app organization
> - Messages (iMessage, SMS, and MMS)
> - Ringtones
> - Visual Voicemails

There are some caveats to consider when using iCloud Backup, though:

- as already mentioned, purchases no longer available in the iTunes Store, App Store or iBookstore may not be restored
- backup of purchased music is not available in all countries
- backups of purchased movies and TV shows are U.S. only
- music, movies, and TV shows that you did not purchase from the iTunes Store are not included
- any podcasts, audio books or photos that you originally synced from your computer are excluded

I warmly recommend that you read [Choosing an iOS backup method (Should I use iTunes or iCloud to back up my iOS device?)](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5262) for more information on iTunes and iCloud backups and which may the right choice for you.

**If the size of your backup exceeds the 5 GB free storage limit**, an alternative to purchasing additional storage is to restrict which app data will be backed up. You can do that in Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage.